# Unity 2d Screen is black when game loads WebGL

Tags: unity-webgl

When running my game in the unity engine it works fine but when I click build and run, it does so and the game loads in the webpage, but then the screen is simply black. I can still hear the in game music, so the game is running, just black. I pressed f12 to see the html for the page and as soon as the game loads when the screen goes black it throws like 300 something of the same warning saying

```
GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Draw framebuffer is incomplete.
```

**The error is just below the doctype declaration, on the main page (image)**

[image: error]

Does anyone have any idea what this means or how to fix this? I don't even know if this is the source of the error its just a guess.